# Generating Twilio Python client capability tokens

Tags: python, twilio

Folks:
I am trying to get Twilio's "https://github.com/TwilioDevEd/browser-calls-flask" example to work. However, I am running into quite a few hurdles and reaching a conclusion that these examples, as well as Python libraries, are not being maintained. For example, all sample code seems to advise as follows (see [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/client/javascript/quickstart#create-capability-tokens)):

```
@app.route('/token', methods=['GET'])
def get_capability_token():
"""Respond to incoming requests."""

...

capability = ClientCapabilityToken(account_sid, auth_token)
...
token = capability.generate()

return Response(token, mimetype='application/jwt')
```

However, my `token` throws an error at runtime saying that method `generate()` does not exist. I have tried hacking my way around the samples code (see [here](https://github.com/TwilioDevEd/browser-calls-flask/issues/9) and [here](https://github.com/TwilioDevEd/browser-calls-flask/issues/10)), but nothing results in a working system. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

-Raj

Answer (score 0):

Needed to fix Twilio samples by changing token generation code to say:
`token = capability.to_jwt().decode('utf-8')`. See [the pull request](https://github.com/TwilioDevEd/browser-calls-flask/pull/11).